# rigidbodies not working with a lot of objects

Tags: rigidbody

i have added a lot of objects with rigidbodies but some rigidbody objects are not working. i think its happening because there are a lot of objects **: /**. i have tried searching on web but i didnt found any answer.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16or602_RENpfHsaVclrzY5TM0nCAwBl4/view?usp=sharing
FIle link: [image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i have added the file now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This last cube is not part of the same *Rigid Body World* collection, so remove the second collection, add a new one, and choose *RigidBodyWorld* instead of *RigidBodyWorld.011*:

[image]

*RigidBodyWorld* is a kind of ghost collection that is created and selected by default in the *Scene* panel > *Rigid Body World* when you create a rigid body object, more explanations give [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR3p5vkG4t4) by Blender Frenzy. You can also put your rigid body objects in a real outliner collection if you want, in this case, select it in the *Scene* panel:

[image]